# What are these constraints called? Where can I find out more?

Tags: php, permissions, acl, access-control

Ok, I have been trying to get a 'custom' ACL to work with extra constraints. A normal ACL check is something like:

```
if(aclCheck($user, 'edit', 'really_important_value')){
    // Allow $user to 'edit' the 'really_important_value'.
} else {
    // Deny $user to 'edit' the 'really_important_value'.
}
```

But, if different users have different bounds for 'really_important_value' (user 1 can enter a value between 10 and 50, user 2 can edit a value between 20 and 60) - where do these constraints belong? Are they called constraints, bounds, attributes, parameters, rules or something else? I can't find any examples in any manual for other ACLs or existing application!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They sound like constraints. I'm not sure what the question is. Are you designing an ACL of your own or trying to work with an existing one?

Comment: Fanis has a good point. You mention a manual and an application, what are these? Without knowing this it is next to impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: I'm working on a custom ACL for our custom application. I've looked through manuals such as phpACL etc to no avail. Either an example from first principles or a reference to something existing would be fab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [Writing Conditional ACL Rules with Assertions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link: it does seem as if assertions are as close to what I was looking for as I can get, but not quite as dynamic as I'd hoped!